# Changing Search Bar placeholder text font in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uisearchbar, uifont

I am trying to change the font of the placeholder text in the search bar within my Search Display Controller. I was looking at some examples and I tried to implement them but as they are in Objective-C, I wasn't able to find any that I could get to work.

For example, I tried this one:

```
UITextField *textField = [[searchBar subviews] objectAtIndex:1]; 
[textField setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:40]];
```

But I was unable to get past `var textField: UITextField = UISearchBar`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 34):

```
 //SearchBar Text
    let textFieldInsideUISearchBar = dashBoardSearchBar.valueForKey("searchField") as? UITextField
textFieldInsideUISearchBar?.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

//SearchBar Placeholder    
     let textFieldInsideUISearchBarLabel = textFieldInsideUISearchBar!.valueForKey("placeholderLabel") as? UILabel
textFieldInsideUISearchBarLabel?.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

Comment: "placeholderLabel" does not seem to work anymore (iOS10), but changing the font of the "searchField" changes both, the placeholder font and the text font as well

Answer (score 22):

Set placeholder text font size:

```
UILabel.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)
```

set search text font size:

```
UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)
```

Answer (score 16):

```
searchBar.searchTextField.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 40)
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! When you answer a question you should include some kind of explanation, like what the author did wrong and what you did to fix it. I'm telling you this because your answer has been flagged as low-quality and is currently being reviewed. You can [edit] your answer by clicking the "Edit" button.

Comment: This is available just in iOS 13 and above

Answer (score 15):

This is the easiest practise for changing the Font or any other similar changes in the textfield of searchBar. ***I have been using XCode 8.4, Swift 3.x, iOS 10.x.***

```
extension UISearchBar {

func change(textFont : UIFont?) {

    for view : UIView in (self.subviews[0]).subviews {

        if let textField = view as? UITextField {
            textField.font = textFont
        }
    }
} }
```

The above code can be called directly where you make an IBOutlet of the searchBar...

```
@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar! {
    didSet {
        searchBar.change(textFont: GlobalConstants.Font.avenirBook14)
    }
}
```

Comment: Its not working; Its just working in very simple way like following:
`searchBar.searchTextField.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 40)`

Tested on XCode: 11.3 OS: 13.3

Answer (score 9):

There is even an easier way in **Swift 5**:

```
searchBar[keyPath: \.searchTextField].font = UIFont(...)
```

Comment: Interesting syntax!

Comment: Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Comment: @Markon are you using Swift 5? Maybe there’s some other problem, but Xcode shows this line by mistake? Or maybe try to clear build

Answer (score 8):

In iOS 8 ,try this

```
for subView in searchBar.subviews  {
  for subsubView in subView.subviews  {
      if let textField = subsubView as? UITextField {
        textField.attributedPlaceholder =  NSAttributedString(string:NSLocalizedString("Search", comment:""),
          attributes:[NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.orangeColor()])
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Swift 3 version of @Alvin's answer

```
let textFieldInsideUISearchBar = searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField
    let placeholderLabel       = textFieldInsideUISearchBar?.value(forKey: "placeholderLabel") as? UILabel
    placeholderLabel?.font     = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12.0)
```

Comment: Just in case anyone else is struggling to make this work, if you're using storyboards, you need to set a placeholder value on the storyboard's search bar before using this code

Comment: I was using a searchController instead of a searchBar so instead of using ... = searchBar.value... I used ... = searchController.searchBar.value... The difference is when using a searchController directly the searchBar is a property on it so you have to go through the searchBar first to access it.

Answer (score 3):

This works perfectly for ios7 -> ios9 using swift 2:

```
if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
    UITextField.appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses([UISearchBar.self]).font = UI.getInstance.tinyFont
} else {
    func checkSubview(view:UIView)
    for subView in view.subviews {
        if subView is UITextField {
            let textField = subView as! UITextField
            textField.font = UI.getInstance.tinyFont
        } else {
            checkSubview(subView)
        }

    }
    checkSubview(view)
}
```

Just replace UI.getInstance.tinyFont by whichever font you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
let searchBar = UISearchBar()

guard let font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 40.0) else { return }

let attributedString = NSAttributedString(
    string: "Search...",
    attributes: [
        .font: font
    ]
)

searchBar.searchTextField.attributedPlaceholder = attributedString
```